# For is overwriting arraylist

Tags: java, exception, arraylist

I'm doing a code to read 3 names, 3 ages and printing who's the oldest and the youngest ones. I'm saving the objects in a arraylist, but it seems to overwriting the collection, so when I print it, just the last input shows in the string as the oldest and the youngest at same time. Can anyone help me with that?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Exercise2 {

    static class Person{
        String name;
        int age;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        public void setName(){
            System.out.println("Input the name:");
            nome = input.next();
            input.nextLine();
        }

        public void setAge(){
            System.out.println("Input the age:");
            idade = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
        }
    }

    static public void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Person> person = new ArrayList<Person>();
        Person p = new Person();
        Person aux = new Person();
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for(i = 0; i< 3; i++){
            p.setName();
            p.setAge();
            person.add(i,p);
            System.out.println( person.toString() );
            System.out.println( person.size() );
        }

        for(i = 0; i != 2; i++){
            for(j = 0; j != 2; j++){
                if(person.get(i).age > person.get(j).age){
                    aux.age = person.get(i).age;
                    person.get(i).age = pessoa.get(j).age;
                    person.get(j).age = aux.age;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(person.get(i).name + " is the youngest and " + person.get(j).name + " is the oldest.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating one `Person` instance and adding it to a list multiple times.

Comment: *"For is overwriting arraylist"*, no *you* overwrite the values in that list, not the `for` loop ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating one `Person` instance and adding it to list multiple times. You should create new instance each time in `for` loop and add to `List<Person>`.

```
//Declare with List instead of ArrayList
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

for(i = 0; i< 3; i++){
  Person p = new Person();// Move this line here.
  p.setName("Jon"); // Read attribute from file
  p.setAge(33);
  people.add(p);//Index should not mentioned
  ....
}
```

Another point, Your setter method of `Person` model is not correct. You should pass argument at setter method. For example look at following model class. Than at `main` method you should read file with `Scanner` and populate `List<Person>` using these setter methods.

```
class Person{
    String name;
    int age;

    public void setName(String name){
      this.name=name;
    }

    public void setAge(int age){
      this.age=age.
    }
   }
```

Comment: To create 3 new Persons.

Comment: Because it will create only 1 person.

Comment: @Apurva, outside of for loop doen't create new instance. It will be same person instance throughout the List.